# How can i test this function based view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i'm trying to do a TestCase on a function based view in django and i'm getting the:
AssertionError: 200 != 302 : Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200 (expected 302) Error.
The view is a like in a post on a blog project, i think i'm doing the post in the wrong way but i'm not understanding how to do the test in the correct way.

```
This is my related views:

## view where the button like appears
class PostDetailView(FormMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    form_class = CreateComments

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        actual_post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        liked = False
        if actual_post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        context['total_likes'] = actual_post.total_likes()
        context['liked'] = liked
        context['form'] = CreateComments()

        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.blog_post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form.save()
        return super(PostDetailView, self).form_valid(form)

# related model:
class Post(models.Model):

    """Model representing a blog post"""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter a post title')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Enter a description for the post')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_post')

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object"""
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to acces a detail record for this book"""
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


## view of the proper like:

def LikeView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))

    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post-detail', args=[str(pk)]))

## urls.py

path('post/like/<int:pk>/', LikeView, name='like-post'),

## test with error:

    def test_likes(self):
        login = self.client.login(username='user1', password='user1senha')
        post = self.client.get(reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': '1'}))
        response = self.client.post(reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': '1'}), post.context['object'].likes.add(post.context['user']))
        self.assertEqual(response.context['total_likes'], 1)

    def test_likes_redirects_to_correct_template(self):
        login = self.client.login(username='user1', password='user1senha')
        post = self.client.get(reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': '1'}))
        response = self.client.post(reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': '1'}), post.context['object'].likes.add(post.context['user']))
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': '1'}))
```

in these tests i'm getting to add the like but the assertRedirects fail, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your post is returning what you expect.  I suggest looking at the response in your debugger (or just use print(response) in front of the assertRedirects statement).  Perhaps there is an error during the post.

Good news is the test is likely working as designed.

Comment: it's strange because when i ran the test manually, it's working correctly, this is what the response is returning: <TemplateResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
it's incorrect but i don't why, manually it's working as expected, in the test it's giving me this 200 status_code when it should be 302